# UIImageView height not height of child image's height after autolayout constraints.

Tags: ios, uiimageview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

My goal:

- Image's width == width of the screen.
- Aspect ratio stays in tact, so the height will adjust automatically.
- The height of the UIImageView == height of the child image's height. *(what is currently not working as you will see below)*

I am using XCode 6, AutoLayout constraints storyboard to complete this.

---

Look at the following 2 screenshots to see (1) what the app currently looks like and (2) what I need fixed. 
[image: what app currently looks like]

As you can see on the left side of the screenshot, I have my storyboard with the imageview selected.

- The imageview's width is covering the screen's width
- I have set the background color to black so you can see how the imageview stretches it's height.
- Look on the far right side of the screenshot to see the 3 constraints I have set so far. The first 2 are to fit the imageview on the screen and the last is to make sure it goes below the navigation bar. Pretty normal constraints.

So far looking at the screenshot, my first 2 goals are satisfied. The image's width is the width of the screen (you can see on the iPhone 4 preview in the screenshot) and the aspect ratio stays in tact.

---

Now, this is the issue I am having...

[image: what is wrong]

How do I get rid of that black space above and below the image? That black is coming from the imageview. **I want the imageview to be the same height as the image inside of it is set as.**

---

Some guesses I have:

- Should I create constraints for each of the size classes available? So instead of editing wAny and hAny, I should set the imageview's height constraint for iPhones and one for iPad using their specific size classes?
- If I remove the leading and trailing contraints, it seems to get rid of the black space but then the imageview doesn't fit on the screen anymore so the constraint is needed. Any other way to make the imageview's width the width of the screen instead of using these constraints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following constraint to the imageView:

"aspect ratio" constraint with the multiplier set to the imageView's aspect ratio.

For example:

If the dimension of the image is (600 x 300), then the "aspect ratio" mutltiplier will be 2:1

Comment: Yup, that did it! Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you do if the image is loading dynamically and you don't know what the aspect ratio is going to be? Do you have to take the UIImage and calculate the ratio?